# Collapsible Tree

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js, tree

(beginner with D3.JS)

after converting my php request into a JSON:

var JsonConvert = php echo json_encode($res)

I would like to use it in order to create the collapsible tree(D3.JS) 
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

I think a have to replace

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, flare) {
  if (error) throw error;

  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});
```

but I don't know how to proceed. If you can help me

Thanks